# Orientacion a problema

Tags: java

Hola buenas hay un fragmento de un ejercicio que no entiendo como hacerlo en java. El ejercicio es:

> Defina un método ComprobarMarca que reciba la marca del electrodoméstico y la compare con
> los valores de un arreglo constante de 5 marcas y determine si la marca se encuentra en el
> arreglo o no.

No entiendo como declalarlo ni como compararlo
lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
    public class Electrodomestico {
    
    private String nombreElectro,marcaElec;
    private double khw, tiempoDeUso,consumoTotal,CantidadFinalKw;
    static final double ValorKw = 105;
    
    public Electrodomestico(String nombreElec, String marca,double kw,double tiempoUso){
       this.nombreElectro=nombreElec;
       this.marcaElec=marca;
       this.khw=kw;
       this.tiempoDeUso=tiempoUso;
    }

    public String getNombreElectro() {
        return nombreElectro;
    }

    public void setNombreElectro(String nombreElectro) {
        this.nombreElectro = nombreElectro;
    }

    public String getMarcaElec() {
        return marcaElec;
    }

    public void setMarcaElec(String marcaElec) {
        this.marcaElec = marcaElec;
    }

    public double getKhw() {
        return khw;
    }

    public void setKhw(double khw) {
        this.khw = khw;
    }

    public double getTiempoDeUso() {
        return tiempoDeUso;
    }

    public void setTiempoDeUso(double tiempoDeUso) {
        this.tiempoDeUso = tiempoDeUso;
    }
    
    public double CalcularKwh (double tiempoDeUso){
        
       return tiempoDeUso;
    }
    
    public void  CalcularConsumo(){
       
        consumoTotal = (khw)*(tiempoDeUso*30);
        
        if (consumoTotal >=1 && consumoTotal <=20) {
            System.out.println("Bajo consumo");
            
        } else if (consumoTotal >=21 && consumoTotal<=45) {
        System.out.println("Consumo moderado");
            
        }else  {
            System.out.println("Consumo alto");
            
        }
        //valor Kw $105 pesos en chile
        CantidadFinalKw = (khw*30)*ValorKw;
    }
    
    public void Imprimir(){
        
    CalcularConsumo();
    
    System.out.println("El consumo es:"+consumoTotal);
    System.out.println("El valor en pesos es: " + CantidadFinalKw);
    }
    
    public void ComprobarMarca(){
    
    }
    
    public void ComprobarMara(String marcaElec){
        
    String [] marcas =  new String[5];
    marcas[0]= "lg";
    marcas[1]= "madenmsa";
    marcas[2]= "samsung";
    marcas[3]= "fensa";
    marcas[4]= "hisense";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < marcas.length; i++) {
            
            
            
        }
    
    
    }
}
```

Aun así no entiendo como el meotdo reciba un valor, y lo cmpare en un arreglo, estoy estancado en eso

> Un programa que pida el nombre de un electrodoméstico, la marca, el consumo en Kw
> (Kilowatts) y tiempo de uso estimado de un electrodoméstico en horas diarias.
> b. El programa debe calcular el consumo mensual del aparato y el valor de dicho consumo en

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La etiquetas deben indicar elementos o herramientas relevantes a tu pregunta. Poner Java y C++ no dice mucho. ¿Lo estás haciendo en Java o en C++? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: estas asignando diferentes valores en la misma ```posicion [0]```,  investiga como declarar un array y sobre el ```metodo equals()```  ;)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

En tu for puedes hacer algo asi

```
    public Bool ComprobarMara(String marcaElec){
        
    Bool ret = false;
    String [] marcas =  new String[5];
    marcas[0]= "lg";
    marcas[1]= "madenmsa";
    marcas[2]= "samsung";
    marcas[3]= "fensa";
    marcas[4]= "hisense";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < marcas.length; i++) {
               if(marcas[i].equals(marcaElec)){
               ret = true;
                }                     
        }
   return ret;
    }
```

Lo que hace el codigo es iterar tu lista la variable "i" va tomando los valores 0 1 2 3 4 ... dentro de esa iteracion verifica si el valor que esta dentro de marcas[0]..marcas[1]...marcas[2]... es igual al texto de marcaElec si es igual retorna TRUE sino retorna false

Aparte cambie el tipo de retorno de tu funcion a un tipo Bool, para que sepas el resultado, Bool puede tomar solamente los valores true ; false